# Java: Ask root privileges on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, root

How to call the authentication window, to grant access for root for a while for current application, from a class.
for example, I'm writing some app to work with partitions, so it need's root privileges to execute some things.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Java-Gnome: http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net

Comment: I would advise you to run it as a user with sudo access. This isn't exactly Java's cup of tea - it's philosophy is "write once, run everywhere" - almost anything you need root access for is not going to be cross platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can't do that with Java. The best way to do is, maybe you can detect that program is not run as `sudo` so you can ask users to shutdown the program and relaunch as super user. (for this solution, I'd prefer choosing a file or directory from system files and check whether it is writable or not. e.g. `new File("/usr/bin/ls").isWritable()`)

Other ways might be launching Desktop Environment-specific authentication windows. e.g. There is [**Java-gnome**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-gnome) but as you might expect, not all users supposed to use GNOME. So there is not really a universal solution and all comes with tons of dependencies. Java is not designed for this.

The best thing is to check super user privileges with a trick on startup. Maybe you can elaborate your problem and we can come up with a solution that does not require root access.