# How do I run an sh file from Java and ask for root permissions to do so?

Tags: java, linux, sh

I want to make a program with a GUI that controls Intel Turbo Boost through `intel_pstate/no_turbo`.

`btnDisable` will trigger:

```
echo -n 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

`btnEnable` will trigger:

```
echo -n 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

However, I want to run those commands from a `.sh` file, and ask for root permissions to do so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I would simply print an error saying something like "need to be run as root" when it fails

Comment: but I want the program to ask for root permissions and run it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828036/is-there-a-way-for-a-java-app-to-gain-root-permissions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115182/java-ask-root-privileges-on-ubuntu - it's fairly non-standard to especially for java applications to request root.